# How did Ryu Yamada get his copy power?

Tags: yamada-and-the-7-witches

Ryu Yamada and other members of Supernatural research club found out that witches gained their power due to their desires. How about for Ryu Yamada, how did he get his copy power and what was his desire?

Comment: Did he get his power because he wanted to be like everyone else? Ergo he could copy people